# MySQL query VALUES($1, $2)[ req.body.number1, req.body.number2] are not working?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

What is wrong with this query, if I replace the $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 with actual values it works,

here is my code.

```
  let queryText = "INSERT INTO`calculator_challenge`.`calculations`
(`number1`, `operator`, `number2`, `total`, `created_at`) 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5);";

  pool.query(queryText, [calc_obj.number1, calc_obj.operator, calc_obj.number2, calc_obj.total, calc_obj.created_at], (error, result, fields) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
});
```

Comment: As shown here, there is no space after "INTO" which may cause issues on some DBMS. However if it works when you interpolate the paceholders, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Update the code as follows: (I included some quotes)

```
let queryText = "INSERT INTO`calculator_challenge`.`calculations`(`number1`, `operator`, `number2`, `total`, `created_at`) VALUES ('$1', '$2', '$3', '$4', '$5')";
```